# Adding a settings icon to toggle configuration for Watch Face (Android Wear)

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I currently have an android wear watch face developed.  I recently tried implementing configurations to the users. Everything works except I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong to not get a settings icon under my watch face.

If anyone could help and tell me what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it!

Here is the code to add wearable configurations from my manifest file.

```
 <service
    android:name=".EleganceTick"
    android:label="@string/analog_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
        android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog_circular" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
        android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog_circular" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction"
        android:value="com.peacockethan.elegancewatchface.watchface.CONFIG_ELEGANCE" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>


<activity
    android:name=".EleganceWatchFaceWearableConfigActivity"
    android:label="Elegance watch face configuration" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.peacockethan.elegancewatchface.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_ELEGANCE" />
        <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WEARABLE_CONFIGURATION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your companion app manifest add the below:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
             android:resource="@xml/watch_face"/>
```

And make sure you have the same version in both manifests and in the watch_face.xml file on the app side

Answer (score 0):

add this to the service tag in wear menifest.

```
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionConfigurationAction"
            android:value="com.frillroid.watchface.CONFIG_ANALOG" />
```

add this intent filter to the activity tag in mobile

```
                      <action android:name="com.frillroid.watchface.CONFIG_ANALOG" />
                      <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: That's if I want to add the configuration in a mobile companion app right? I did this but decided I wanted the configuration to be watch side, do you know why my version of this for a wearable configuration is not working?